# is it correct way to check function input values?

Tags: perl, input, parameters

please review the code:
I want to check input parameters of function, Domian Conway in PBP offer to use croak, is it correct?
i change code to pass http://perlcritic.com/ but 
may be added
    $rs = say "$r->{foo} <= $check_value";
excess

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
##############################################################################
#      $URL: http://mishin.narod.ru $
#     $Date: 2011-11-01 16:32:04 +0400 (Nov, 01 Nov 2011) $
#   $Author: mishnik $
# $Revision: 1.02 $
#   $Source: test  check variables $
#   $Description:  check input parameters of function
#   $ Domian Conway in PBP offer to use croak, is it correct? $
#   01-11-2011:
#   put question to
#   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963866/is-it-correct-way-to-check-function-input-values
##############################################################################

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Carp qw(cluck carp);
use Data::Dumper;
use Readonly;
use autodie;

our $VERSION = '0.01';

Readonly my $CHECK_LEVEL => 100;

my %filials;
my $ref_hash = \%filials;
my @test     = qw/444 33a 2 d 300 ffd 22/;
my $ret;
for my $test_val (@test) {
    $filials{foo} = $test_val;
    $ret = test_var( \%filials, $CHECK_LEVEL )
      || carp("couldn't invoke test_var \%filials, $CHECK_LEVEL ");
}

sub test_var {
    my $r           = shift;
    my $check_value = shift;

    #check if input parameters is correct
    carp( "ERROR: \$r->{foo} is not defined or not number, \$r:\n" . Dumper($r) )
      if !defined $r->{foo}
          || $r->{foo} !~ /^\d+$/xms;

    #check values by business rule
    if ( $r->{foo} > $check_value ) {
        say "$r->{foo} > $check_value";
    }
    else {
        say "$r->{foo} <= $check_value";
    }
    return 1;
}
```

so 
my perlcritic_profile.perlcriticrc is only

```
severity = 1

[-InputOutput::RequireCheckedSyscalls]
```

old version

```
use 5.01;
use Carp;
use Data::Dumper;
my %filials;
$filials{boo} = 200;
$filials{foo} = 300;
my $ref_hash = \%filials;
my @test     = qw/444 33a 2 d 300 ffd 22/;

for $test_val (@test) {
    $filials{foo} = $test_val;
    test_var( \%filials );
}

sub test_var {
    my $r = shift;
    croak(  "Value \$r->{foo}***$r->{foo}*** is not defined or not number."
          . "\nDump \$r="
          . Dumper($r) )
      if !defined $r->{foo}
          || $r->{foo} !~ /^\d+$/;
    say $r->{foo};
    if ( $r->{foo} > 100 ) {
        say '$r->{foo} > 100';
    }
    else {
        say '$r->{foo} <= 100';
    }
}
```

2Alexandr Ciornii
use the module Attribute:: Signature is also not suitable because of an error
CODE package attribute may clash with future reserved word: returns at - line 46
CODE package attributes may clash with future reserved words: with: returns at - line 60

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
##############################################################################
#      $URL: http://mishin.narod.ru $
#     $Date: 2011-11-01 16:32:04 +0400 (Nov, 01 Nov 2011) $
#   $Author: mishnik $
# $Revision: 1.02 $
#   $Source: test  check variables $
#   $Description:  check input parameters of function
#   $ Domian Conway in PBP offer to use croak, is it correct? $
#   01-11-2011:
#   put question to
#   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963866/is-it-correct-way-to-check-function-input-values
##############################################################################

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Carp qw(cluck carp);
use Data::Dumper;
use Readonly;

#use autodie;
use Attribute::Signature;

our $VERSION = '0.01';

#run main procedure
main();

sub main : returns(integer) {

    #make test for chack input parameters
    Readonly my $CHECK_LEVEL => 100;
    my %filials;
    my $ref_hash = \%filials;
    my @test     = qw/444 33a 2 d 300 ffd 22/;
    my $ret;
    for my $test_val (@test) {
        $ref_hash->{foo} = $test_val;
        $ret = test_var( $ref_hash->{foo}, $CHECK_LEVEL )
          || carp("couldn't invoke test_var \%filials, $CHECK_LEVEL ");
    }

    return 1;
}

sub test_var : with(integer, integer) returns(integer) {
    my $evaluated_value = shift;
    my $check_value     = shift;

    #check values by business rule
    if ( $evaluated_value > $check_value ) {
        say "$evaluated_value > $check_value";
    }
    else {
        say "$evaluated_value <= $check_value";
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I would live the old version in the question, otherwise nobody will understand the answers. Second you don't have to do everything Perl::Critic says. Checking the return value of `say` is a little bit too much if you are writing to the console and not to a file.

Comment: `s/use 5.01/use 5.010/`  equivalent, but clearer.

Comment: thanks, yes old version - useful

Answer (score 5):

Some comments

- use strict and warnings it will help you detect errors

  ```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  ```
- you might consider checking [Perl::Critic](http://p3rl.org/Perl::Critic) (there is an [online](http://perlcritic.com/) version)
- always declare variables: even loop iterators

  ```
  for my $test_val (@test) {
  ```
- strings in single quotes are not interpolated (a `$` is printed as `$`). Use double quotes:

  ```
  say "$r->{foo} > 100";
  ```
- `croak` terminates the program. Since in you test you wanted to check more than one value use `carp`: it will print a warning but continue
- always use `return` at the end of a subroutine: it will help to make explicit what is returned (otherwise perl automatically returns the result of the last performed evaluation)

Comment: thanks i make code to pass http://perlcritic.com/ 
and carp: is super function that is necessary for me

Comment: and now, do you think is it all ok?

Comment: Don't check for the return value of say. If will hardly fail when writing to standard output. And in any case if you are not able to write to standard out it will be impossible to generate an error. Check for the return value of print/say when you are writing to a file (in this case something could go wrong)

Comment: i think http://stackoverflow.com/ needed version of answer such as in  https://gist.github.com

Answer (score 4):

The first issues I see:

- no `use strict; use warnings;` at the top
- single quotes in the `say` argument keep the variables from being expanded

Try [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) !

Comment: i think use 5.01; add this automatically, but I was wrong, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used [Attribute::Signature](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Attribute::Signature) for some time, even released a new version. But later decided that for me sub params are too rare a problem, so I decided to stop using it.

Comment: i try this module, but i had a problen